# Azure mandatory Tag

Tags: azure, tags, policy

help me to make the mandatory tag using azure policy and users are not allowed to give their own tag name. the below code mandatory the mentioned tags and not to control the disallowed other tags

```
{   
  "mode": "All",   
  "policyRule": {   
    "if": {  
      "anyOf": [  
        {  
          "field": "tags['environment']",  
          "exists": "false"  
        },  
        {  
          "field": "tags['Location']",  
          "exists": "false"  
        }  
      ]  
    },  
    "then": {  
      "effect": "deny"  
    }  
  },  
  "parameters": {}   
}
```

Comment: Could you please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/govern-tags ..may it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to make changes with Tag in Azure Policy

```
"policyRule": {
    "if": {
        "allOf": [{
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
            "field": "name",
            "like": "prd-*"
        },
        {
            "field": "tags['Env']",
            "notEquals": "Production"
        }

    ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "modify",
        "details": {
            "roleDefinitionIds": [
                "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
            ],
            "operations": [{
                "operation": "addOrReplace",
                "field": "tags['Env']",
                "value": "Production"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

for further information could you please check the [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/govern-tags) documentation